# Sortable list elements glitches for complex css lists

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to implement a sortable feature on a html nested list using [jquery Sortable](http://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/) Plugin. Based on its tutorial.

It works good for simple lists with no css, but it glitches if I apply some styles. And by glitch I mean the animation flies away from the cursor.

**My tree:**

```
<ul class="simple">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2
        <ul><li>Item 2.1</li></ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JS:**

```
var oldContainer;
$(".simple").sortable({
  group: 'nested',
  afterMove: function (placeholder, container) {
    if(oldContainer != container){
      if(oldContainer)
        oldContainer.el.removeClass("active");
      container.el.addClass("active");
      oldContainer = container;
    }
  },
  onDrop: function (item, container, _super) {
    container.el.removeClass("active");
    _super(item);
  }
});
```

I can't post the css as it is too big. Here's a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexix/GpdgF/2624/).

I can't tell if its due to my coding or if the plugin wasn't designed to be used this way.
My question is, how can I fix the animation? or what other plugin should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in relative positioned list items, it seems that the plugin has problems to calculate left and top position if list items are relative, so it returns position relative to the first non static positioned parent. On the other hand, removing the position property will lead to problems with `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements because of the absolute positioning, since pseudo content is inserted inside a containing element.

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/7x7Wz/)** is an example that roughly works with default static positioning. I hope it will serve the purpose.